# Regular expression pattern does not work in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, regex, string, match

I need to check wether my string matches this regular expression pattern: `\+?\d{0,3}`
(This pattern has been tested here: http://regexpal.com and it seems all right.)

This is what I do:

```
NSString * proposedNewString = @"+3";    
NSString * pattern = @"\\+?\\d{0,3}";
NSError * err = nil;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&err];
if (err) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't create regex with given string and options");
    return NO;
}

NSPredicate * myTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '%@'", regex];

NSLog(@"proposed str = %@", proposedNewString);
if ([myTest evaluateWithObject:proposedNewString]) {
    NSLog(@"yes");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"no");
}
```

I expect it to print out `yes`, but for some reason it prints `no`. Maybe I messed up the backslashes or quotes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "MATCHES" operator in a predicate format expects as argument a *pattern string*,
not a regular expression (and you must not enclose `%@` in quotation marks).
So this produces the expected result "yes":

```
NSString * proposedNewString = @"+3";    
NSString * pattern = @"\\+?\\d{0,3}";
NSPredicate * myTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", pattern];
if ([myTest evaluateWithObject:proposedNewString]) {
    NSLog(@"yes");
} else {
    NSLog(@"no");
}
```

Alternatively, use one of the `NSRegularExpression` methods instead of a predicate, for example

```
if ([regex numberOfMatchesInString:proposedNewString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [proposedNewString length])] > 0) {
    NSLog(@"yes");
} else {
    NSLog(@"no");
}
```

Comment: when i just not enclose `%@` my app crashes with message `2014-09-01 19:48:30.518 MyApp[6686:60b] proposed str = +3`
`2014-09-01 19:48:30.520 MyApp[6686:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't create a regex expression from object <NSRegularExpression: 0x146f0c30> \+?\d{0,3} 0x1.'` but after i have change in addition `evaluateWithObject:` to your `numberOfMathcesInString:options:range` it seems to be work. So thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @MikhailZinkovsky: Please have a look at the first part of my answer again. For `predicateWithFormat`, you have to pass the *pattern string* `pattern`, not the regular expression `regex`. I have tested that code and it worked for me.

Comment: yes you are totally right it was my stupid fail. Thank you a lot.